# Million dollar Question for me!

Tags: rating

I am from India,passionate about chess.What is the actual procedure to become a professional player.Recently my parents are planning to send me to USA for graduation,If that happens will I able to represent my country?Or that doesn't happen(seen Nakamura Japanese Origin representing USA!!!!)Also heard that 1200 points will  be given as default like chess.com to a player who registerd for professional chess.Is that true??Friends help me out!!!!

Comment: Please define 'professional'.

Comment: Above 2000 EloRating is what i think as professional

Comment: So I think that you're really asking is, "How do I become a FIDE Candidate Master"?

Answer (score 2):

> What is the actual procedure to become a professional player

First you need to be born with the necessary talent. Very few are. Then you need to spend years studying and playing chess until you are so much better than most other players that you can actually earn enough money to live.

> Recently my parents are planning to send me to USA for graduation,If
>   that happens will I able to represent my country?

Almost certainly not. Both India and the US have very many excellent chess players. It is extremely unlikely that you will get into either country's top 10 any time soon, if ever.

> Also heard that 1200 points will be given as default like chess.com to
>   a player who registerd for professional chess.Is that true??

You will not be *given* anything, as a default or otherwise. What will happen if you play in rated tournaments is that a default value of 1200 will be used as your estimated rating for ratings calculations until such time as you actually manage to at least draw a game against a rated player. At that time you can be given a real rating.